# how to protect or compress visual basic 6 compiled exe file?

Tags: vb6, resources, obfuscation, protector

I compiled a vb6 project.
I need to protect exe file with protector or compressor so that users can not unresource that.
please help me to find free softwares for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can completely protect your program from being decompiled but you can make it harder. One thing you can do is use an *Obfuscator*. Basically, what an *Obfuscator* does is make your code unreadable if it's decompiled.

One program that I used to use was ***VB Decompiler Pro***. I don't think it's free but it has a tool in it that'll obfuscate your program. The main purpose of the program is to decompile a VB program. But you can use the "Obfuscate Project" tool that is found in the program to obfuscate your VB6 program.

There may be other free obfuscators out there. Google them. The one I mentioned above is the only one I've used.

You can read more about *Obfuscation*  [from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29).

Comment: i am useing  these softwares always but not enough (for example) : upx - The Enigma Protector - PECompact GUI -pelock